# How can I change this folder name set to a variable

Tags: powershell

Ok so in my declaration portion of my script i set this path:

```
$temp = "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Projects\CCMSextract\temp"
```

after i do some processing i want to change the name of the folder temp to

```
CCMSEXTmmddyy
```

I have this for the date

```
$a = get-date
$b = get-date.ToString('MMddyy')
$b
```

how can I change the folder to be something like

```
 $temp = \\path\CCMSextract$b
```

I was thinking rename-item but I need to actually change the name of the folder not just the variable. Might be a simple solution. Not sure. Help please!

I've tried

```
Rename-Item $temp = \\path\CCMSextract$b
```

I suppose I could make a directory item and then copy everything over but there's gotta be as simpler way!

Comment: I don't think the way you are using `rename-item` is correct.

Comment: maybe this? `rename-item -path "$temp" -newname "CCMS$b"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. The syntax is `Rename-Item <old path> <new path>` so do something like:

```
Rename-Item $temp "\\CCMSExtract$b"
```

Answer (score 1):

So in this context $temp is just a string.  Powershell doesn't know that its a folder.  Try:

```
$newFolder = '\\path\CCMSextract' + $b
Rename-Item -path $temp -NewName $newFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and it works

```
$temp.replace("temp","CCMSextract$b")
```

Tested as below

```
PS C:\> $temp = "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Projects\CCMSextract\temp"
PS C:\> echo $temp
\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Projects\CCMSextract\temp

PS C:\> $b = get-date

PS C:\> $temp = $temp.replace("temp","CCMSextract$b")
PS C:\> echo $temp
\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Projects\CCMSextract\CCMSextract05/20/2014 22:35:37
```